# How does scribd prevent download

Tags: drm, scribd

when reading BOOKS on scribd.com the download functionality is not enabled. even browsing through the html source code I was unable to download the actual book. Great stuff ... but HOW did they do this ?
I am looking to implement something similar, to display a pdf (or converted from pdf) in such a way that the visitor cannot download the file

Most solutions I have seen are based on obfusticating the url.. but with a little effort people can find the url and download the file. ScribD seems to have covered this quite well..

Any suggestions , ideas how to implement such a download protection ?

Comment: Ultimately, it's all going to be obfuscation unless you require users to have some kind of proprietary plugin, because the data has to be available to be rendered by the browser. That's not to say you can't try, but be aware that if you have determined users, you are entering an arms race with them, [as these search results for "download scribd" illustrate](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=download+scribd&t=ffsb&ia=web).

Comment: Yes I agree in an arms race.. but at the moment all the tricks shared on downloading do not work. But besides the hacking part... any ideas how they implemented their current solution ?

Comment: I don't have an account on scribd, so can't see any of these "protected" books. I clicked through to a preview of one, and was able to freely copy the text out of it, and the HTML source wasn't even particularly obfuscated, so I'm guessing there's a different system for the ones you're talking about?

Comment: Jesus, I just looked at the JSON it uses to fetch the next page, and that has got to be the most inefficient ebook format ever invented: a JSON object for every single word on the page! Still no attempt at obfuscation, though, just an awful lot of tracking.

Comment: If it is all json, then how can they do images or tables etc ?

Comment: The same way you can in HTML, or any other markup language or document format. I didn't look too much into the details, I was just seeing how easy it would be to scrape the data before it was rendered to the page (conclusion: very easy), and was amused at the ugliness of the format.

Answer (score 2):

It actually works dinamically building the HTML based on AJAX requests made while you're flipping pages. It is not image based. That's why you're finding it difficult to download the content.

However, it is not that safe for now. I present a solution below to download books that is working today (27th Jan 2020) not for teaching you how to do that (it is not legal), but to show you how you should prevent (or, at least, making it harder) users from downloading content if you're building something similar.

If you have a paid account and open the book page (the one that opens when you click 'Start Reading'), you can download an image of each book page by loading a library such as dom-to-image.

For instance, you could load the library using the developer tools (all code shown below must be typed in the page console):

```
if (injectDomToImage == undefined) {
    var injectDomToImage = document.createElement('script');
    injectDomToImage.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dom-to-image/2.6.0/dom-to-image.min.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(injectDomToImage);
}
```

And then, you could define functions such as these:

```
function downloadPage(page, prefix) {
    domtoimage.toJpeg(document.getElementsByClassName('reader_and_banner_container')[0], {
            quality: 1,
        })
        .then(function(dataUrl) {
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.download = `${prefix}_page_${page}.jpg`;
            link.href = dataUrl;
            link.click();
            nextPage(page, prefix);
        });
}

function checkPageChanged(page, oldPageCounter, prefix) {
    let newPageCounter = $('.page_counter').html();
    if (oldPageCounter === newPageCounter) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            checkPageChanged(page, oldPageCounter, prefix);
        }, 500);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
            downloadPage(page + 1, prefix);
        }, 500);
    }
}

function nextPage(page, prefix) {
    let oldPageCounter = $('.page_counter').html();
    $('.next_btn').trigger('click');
    // Wait until page counter has changed (page loading has finished).
    checkPageChanged(page + 1, oldPageCounter, prefix);
}

function download(prefix) {
    downloadPage(1, prefix);
}
```

Finally, you could download each book page as a JPG image using:

```
download('test_');
```

It will download each page as test_page_.jpg

In order to prevent such type of 'robot', they could, for example, have used Re-CAPTCHA v3 that works in background seeking for 'robot'-like behaviour.